# Signals for entered/exited events in TabView

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, tabview, qt5.3

I have a `TabView`, which has 3 `Tab`s, Say `tab1`, `tab2`, `tab3`. Each `Tab` has some widgets.
I want to have some kind of signalling mechanism, so that when I enter `tab3`, I want to set the state of some of the widgets (e.g. a `TextField`) within `tab3` and when I leave it, I want to reset their state.

Any pointers on how to achieve this? When I read Qt 5.3 documentation about `TabView` and `Tab`, I did not find any signals exposed by them.

Signalling can be within `tab3` or between `Tabview` and `tab3`. I am fine with either of these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `onVisibleChanged` Try this:

```
TabView {

    Tab {
        onVisibleChanged: console.log("hello1 "+visible)
        title: "Red"
        Rectangle { color: "red" }
    }
    Tab {
        onVisibleChanged: console.log("hello2 "+visible)
        title: "Blue"
        Rectangle { color: "blue" }
    }
    Tab {
        onVisibleChanged: console.log("hello3 "+visible)
        title: "Green"
        Rectangle { color: "green" }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to answer my own question, but you were quick. onVisibleChanged, onFocusChanged both worked for me. My qtcreator automatically gave me hints the moment I started typing on (keyword). But I do not see them as part of qt5.3 documentation under Tab.

Comment: @Sandeep Because Tab inherits this property: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#visible-prop So you can use it, but there is no explicit description in doc, you can use this instead: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tab-members.html

Answer (score 0):

On a tab change, visibility of *TWO* tabs changes, on the leaving tab (from `false` to `true`) and on the entering tab (from `true` to `false`). These events are not always serialized. I had to add:

```
onVisibleChanged: {
    if (!this.activeFocus){
        // ...
    }
}
```

But, if you do not actually click on tab but activate it by setting tab's `active` to `true`, the solution above is not enough.
You'd have to use `TabView.currentIndex` to compare it with the static, i.e. declarative tab index. If `onVisibleChanged` is called for the new active tab, then the indexes should be equal.

Here is as example:

```
function refreshButtons(tabIndexStatic){
    if (tabStepsView.currentIndex !== tabIndexStatic)
        return;
    buttonPrev.visible      = tabIndexStatic !== 0
    buttonNext.visible      = tabIndexStatic !== tabStepsView.count - 1
    buttonConvert.visible   = tabIndexStatic === tabStepsView.count - 1
    }
    Tab {
        title: qsTr("Tab 0")
        onVisibleChanged: parent.refreshButtons(0)

        // ...
    }
    Tab {
        title: qsTr("Tab 1")
        onVisibleChanged: parent.refreshButtons(1);
        // ...
    }
    Tab {
        title: "Tab 2"
        onVisibleChanged: tabStepsView.refreshButtons(2)
        // ...
    }
}
```